# Patching a function inside a library

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question about patching.
I have a library A with the following structure

```
A/
  __init__.py
  B/
    __init__.py
    module_B.py
  C/
    __init__.py
    module_C.py
```

- `__init__.py` of A

```
from A.B import module_B
```

- `module_B.py`

```
from A.C.module_C import print_

def run():
    print_()
```

- `module_C.py`

```
def print_():
    print("original")
```

My goal is to patch the `print_` function. I have the following script

```
def _new_print():
    print("patched")

from A.C import module_C
module_C._print = _new_print

from A import module_B

module_B.run() # will still print "original"
```

This won’t work as when I imported the `module_C`, it already imported the original `_print` function in `module_B` when running the `__init__.py` of `A`. So is there any way that I could patch in my script to make the `module_B.run()` output "patched" instead of "original" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution could be

```
def _new_print():
    print("patched")


from A.B import module_B

module_B.print_ = _new_print

module_B.run()
```

Comment: Yes. But do you know why?

Answer (score 2):

When you do `from A.C import module_C`, `A` has to be loaded first. That means that `from A.B import module_B` runs in `A`, which in turn means that `from A.C.module_C import print_` sets `print_` in `B.__dict__` before you ever change it in `C`.

There are three solutions I can think of:

1. Patch the name in `B` instead of, or along with, the one in `C`:

   ```
   from A.B import module_B
   module_B._print = _new_print
   ```
2. Remove the import in `A`.
3. Have `B` reference the actual method in `C` instead of a local reference, which might not be up to date:

   ```
   from A.C import module_C

   def run():
       module_C.print_()
   ```

Which one you choose depends on the specifics of the situation you find yourself in.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping! I went with the first one since it leaves the lib untouched, otherwise it will beat the purpose of patching.

Comment: @user3391299. Don't forget to select the answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to change your `import` in `module_B`:

```
import A.C.module_C

def run():
    A.C.module_C.print_()
```

The key here is you have to patch the function where it is used, rather than where it is defined. If you do `import A.C.module_C`, then these are the same. But if you do `from A.C.module_c import print_`, you are creating a new name in `module_B`. Then patching the `print_` function in `module_C` doesn't affect that `print_` variable in `module_B`.